# SSRS - Show report creation date on header fixed

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

The Actual problem here is to save the date on report created as snapshot and should not change any time user will open to see this report.

I have a problem. We have report snapshots for scheduled reports. So if a report is created by scheduled task on Jan 1 2016, the date on header should appear like

In January ---
As on: January 31, 2016

In February ---
As on: February 28, 2016

And when ever I will open this report it should show this same date on report header and not the current month. My reports are now showing current month for every report we open.

My current code in textbox is

```
=iif(Left(User!Language,2)="fr","En date du ", "As of ") + Code.GetDateString()


Public Function GetDateString() as String
Dim iMonth as integer
Dim sYear as String
Dim thisMonth As New DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 1)
Dim firstDayLastMonth As DateTime
Dim lastDayLastMonth As DateTime

if (Month(Date.Now) = 1) then 
    iMonth = 12
    sYear = CStr(Year(Date.Now)-1)
else
    iMonth = Month(Date.Now) - 1
    sYear = CStr(Year(Date.Now))
end if

firstDayLastMonth = thisMonth.AddMonths(-1)
lastDayLastMonth = thisMonth.AddDays(-1)

Return MonthName(iMonth)  + " " + CStr(Day(lastDayLastMonth)) + ", " + sYear

End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: did you know "=Globals!ExecutionTime" (a.k.a report created time)

Comment: No difference I think. It would show the execution time. If I created the report (snapshot) on Feb 2016 and then if I want to run today on March 10, it would show me the March date and time. I want to see the Feb date time.

Comment: I second the use of `=Globals!ExecutionTime`. In Report Manager, if you set the report to 'render this report from a report snapshot', the expression should match the schedule date/time. Some of my reports are scheduled at 3:33 each morning, and this time shows in the headers all day when people access them.